# Compare CSV Header to Map Class

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a process whereby we have written a class to import a large (ish) CSV into our app using CsvHelper (https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper).

I would like to compare the header to the Map to ensure the header's integrity. We get the CSV file from a 3rd party and I want to ensure it doesn't change over time and thought the best way to do this would be to compare it against the map.

We have a class set up as so (trimmed):

```
public class VisitExport
{
    public int? Count { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerAddress { get; set; }
}
```

And its corresponding map (also trimmed):

```
public class VisitMap : ClassMap<VisitExport>
{
    public VisitMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Count).Name("Count");
        Map(m => m.CustomerName).Name("Customer Name");
        Map(m => m.CustomerAddress).Name("Customer Address");
    }
}
```

This is the code I have for reading the CSV file and it works great. I have a try catch in place for the error but ideally, if it fails specifically for a header miss match, I'd like to handle that specifically.

```
private void fileLoadedLink_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var filePath = string.Empty;
            data = new List<VisitExport>();

            using (OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog())
            {
                openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = new KnownFolder(KnownFolderType.Downloads).Path;
                openFileDialog.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
                openFileDialog.FilterIndex = 2;
                openFileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

                if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    filePath = openFileDialog.FileName;

                    var fileStream = openFileDialog.OpenFile();
                    var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");

                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                    using (var readCsv = new CsvReader(reader, culture))
                    {
                        var map = new VisitMap();
                        readCsv.Context.RegisterClassMap(map);
                        var fileContent = readCsv.GetRecords<VisitExport>();
                        data = fileContent.ToList();
                        fileLoadedLink.Text = filePath;
                        viewModel.IsFileLoaded = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (CsvHelperException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message);
            fileLoadedLink.Text = "Error loading file.";
            viewModel.IsFileLoaded = false;
        }
    }
```

Is there a way of comparing the Csv header vs my map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two basic cases for CSV files with headers: missing CSV columns, and extra CSV columns.  The first is already detected by `CsvHelper` while the detection of the second is not implemented out of the box and requires subclassing of `CsvReader`.

(As CsvHelper maps CSV columns to model properties by name, permuting the order of the columns in the CSV file would not be considered a breaking change.)

Note that this only applies to CSV files that actually contain headers.  Since you are not setting `CsvConfiguration.HasHeaderRecord = false` I assume that this applies to your use case.

Details about each of the two cases follow.

**Missing CSV columns.**

Currently CsvHelper *already* throws an exception by default in such situations.  When unmapped data model properties are found, [`CsvConfiguration.HeaderValidated`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/CsvConfiguration.cs#L73) is invoked.  By default this is set to [`ConfigurationFunctions.HeaderValidated`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/dfd643d1b57a83b7ea5099e92e38f87723baac2c/src/CsvHelper/Configuration/ConfigurationFunctions.cs#L23) whose current behavior is to throw a [`HeaderValidationException`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/HeaderValidationException.cs) if there are any unmapped model properties.  You can replace or extend `HeaderValidated` with logic of your own if you prefer:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
var config = new CsvConfiguration (culture)
{
    HeaderValidated = (args) => 
    { 
         // Add additional logic as required here
        ConfigurationFunctions.HeaderValidated(args); 
    },
};

using (var readCsv  = new CsvReader(reader, config))
{
    // Remainder unchanged
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/llHMaj).

**Extra CSV columns.**

Currently `CsvHelper` does not inform the application when this happens.  See [Throw if csv contains unexpected columns #1032](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1032) which confirms that this is not implemented out of the box.

In a [GitHub comment](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1032#issuecomment-777150033), user [leopignataro](https://github.com/leopignataro) suggests a workaround, which is to subclass [`CsvReader`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/CsvReader.cs) and add the necessary validation logic oneself.  However the version shown in the comment doesn't seem to handle duplicated column names or embedded references.  The following subclass of `CsvHelper` should do this correctly.  It is based on the logic in [`CsvReader.ValidateHeader(ClassMap map, List<InvalidHeader> invalidHeaders)`](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/0d753ff09294b425e4bc5ab346145702eeeb1b6f/src/CsvHelper/CsvReader.cs#L157).  It recursively walks the incoming `ClassMap`, attempts to find a CSV header corresponding to each member or constructor parameter, and flags the index of each one that is mapped.  Afterwards, if there are any unmapped headers, the supplied `Action<CsvContext, List<string>> OnUnmappedCsvHeaders` is invoked to notify the application of the problem and throw some exception if desired:

```
public class ValidatingCsvReader : CsvReader
{
    public ValidatingCsvReader(TextReader reader, CultureInfo culture, bool leaveOpen = false) : this(new CsvParser(reader, culture, leaveOpen)) { }
    public ValidatingCsvReader(TextReader reader, CsvConfiguration configuration) : this(new CsvParser(reader, configuration)) { }
    public ValidatingCsvReader(IParser parser) : base(parser) { }

    public Action<CsvContext, List<string>> OnUnmappedCsvHeaders { get; set; }

    public override void ValidateHeader(Type type)
    {
        base.ValidateHeader(type);
        
        var headerRecord = HeaderRecord;
        var mapped = new BitArray(headerRecord.Length);
        var map = Context.Maps[type];
        FlagMappedHeaders(map, mapped);
        var unmappedHeaders = Enumerable.Range(0, headerRecord.Length).Where(i => !mapped[i]).Select(i => headerRecord[i]).ToList();
        if (unmappedHeaders.Count > 0)
        {
            OnUnmappedCsvHeaders?.Invoke(Context, unmappedHeaders);
        }
    }

    protected virtual void FlagMappedHeaders(ClassMap map, BitArray mapped)
    {
        // Logic adapted from https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/0d753ff09294b425e4bc5ab346145702eeeb1b6f/src/CsvHelper/CsvReader.cs#L157
        // By https://github.com/JoshClose
        foreach (var parameter in map.ParameterMaps)
        {
            if (parameter.Data.Ignore)
                continue;
            if (parameter.Data.IsConstantSet)
                // If ConvertUsing and Constant don't require a header.
                continue;
            if (parameter.Data.IsIndexSet && !parameter.Data.IsNameSet)
                // If there is only an index set, we don't want to validate the header name.
                continue;

            if (parameter.ConstructorTypeMap != null)
            {
                FlagMappedHeaders(parameter.ConstructorTypeMap, mapped);
            }
            else if (parameter.ReferenceMap != null)
            {
                FlagMappedHeaders(parameter.ReferenceMap.Data.Mapping, mapped);
            }
            else
            {
                var index = GetFieldIndex(parameter.Data.Names.ToArray(), parameter.Data.NameIndex, true);
                if (index >= 0)
                    mapped.Set(index, true);
            }
        }

        foreach (var memberMap in map.MemberMaps)
        {
            if (memberMap.Data.Ignore || !CanRead(memberMap))
                continue;
            if (memberMap.Data.ReadingConvertExpression != null || memberMap.Data.IsConstantSet)
                // If ConvertUsing and Constant don't require a header.
                continue;
            if (memberMap.Data.IsIndexSet && !memberMap.Data.IsNameSet)
                // If there is only an index set, we don't want to validate the header name.
                continue;

            var index = GetFieldIndex(memberMap.Data.Names.ToArray(), memberMap.Data.NameIndex, true);
            if (index >= 0)
                mapped.Set(index, true);
        }

        foreach (var referenceMap in map.ReferenceMaps)
        {
            if (!CanRead(referenceMap))
                continue;
                
            FlagMappedHeaders(referenceMap.Data.Mapping, mapped);
        }
    }
}
```

And then in your code, handle the `OnUnmappedCsvHeaders` callback however you would like, such as by throwing a `CsvHelperException` or some other custom exception:

```
using (var readCsv  = new ValidatingCsvReader(reader, culture)
       {
           OnUnmappedCsvHeaders = (context, headers) => throw new CsvHelperException(context, string.Format("Unmapped CSV headers: \"{0}\"", string.Join(",", headers))),
       })
```

Demo fiddles:

- [#2 (your model)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/f8D0rj).
- [#3 (with external references)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tyXUqZ).
- [#4 (duplicate names)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QAh8hH).
- [#5 (using the auto-generated map)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NPW2jN).

This could use additional testing, e.g. for data models with parameterized constructors and additional, mutable properties.

Comment: Best answer I've ever received here. Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2):

How about catching `HeaderValidationException` before catching `CsvHelperException`

```cs
catch (HeaderValidationException ex)
{
    var message = ex.Message.Split('\n')[0];
    var currentHeader = ex.Context.Reader.HeaderRecord;

    message += $"{Environment.NewLine}Header:  \"{string.Join(",", currentHeader)}\"";
    
    Console.WriteLine(message);
    fileLoadedLink.Text = "Error loading file.";
    viewModel.IsFileLoaded = false;
}
catch (CsvHelperException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException != null ? ex.InnerException.Message : ex.Message);
    fileLoadedLink.Text = "Error loading file.";
    viewModel.IsFileLoaded = false;
}
```

Comment: Your message will only show the first missing header.  All missing headers are in the HeaderValidationException's InvalidHeaders array.  So you could do something like, `var invalidHeaders = new List<string>();    
foreach (var header in ex.InvalidHeaders) { invalidHeaders.Add(header.Names[0]); }    
var message = $"Missing Headers: {string.Join(", ", invalidHeaders)}";`